# Components of electric field deriving from potential equetion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

My question is abut finding components of electric field from potential function. $V=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}{r^3}$ (1)

I can write it as $V=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{pz}{r^3}$ (2)

By taking partial derivative

$\vec{E_x}=\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x}}$

$\vec{E_x}=\frac{pz}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\partial\frac{1}{r^3}}{\partial{x}}$

$\vec{E_x}=\frac{pzx\hat{x}}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}$

So is $\vec{E_y}$

$\vec{E_y}=\frac{pzx\hat{y}}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}$

However

$\vec{E_z}=\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\partial{\frac{z}{r^3}}}{\partial{z}}$

$\vec{E_z}=\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{3z^3}{r^3}-\frac{1}{r^3}\right]$

Here I get $\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}\left(3pz\vec{r}-p\hat{z}\right)$

But i am supposed to find

$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}\left(\frac{3\left(\vec{p}\cdot\hat{r}\right)}{r^2}-\vec{p}\right)$

What is my mistake here? I tried but could not see. By the war from (1) to (2) $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}=pr\cos{\alpha}$

$\cos{\alpha}=\frac{z}{r}$

Comment: Right before i wrote" Here i get" that 3z^3 is not the case but 3z^2 instead?

Comment: I would recommend using the spherical gradient instead of the Cartesian one: $\nabla =\hat{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \hat{\theta} \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \hat{\phi} \frac{1}{r \sin{\theta}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$

Comment: There's something wrong with your "supposed to find" expression, because in the parentheses, you have a vector subtracted from a scalar.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).